# Laravel SQL Query difficult

Tags: php, sql, laravel-4

I can't "translate" the SQL Query below to Laravel, how I can make this?

```
SELECT SUM(transactions.amount) AS total, products.name 
FROM transactions, product_stock, product_catalog, products
WHERE transactions.id_product_stock = product_stock.id_prodct_stock
AND product_stock.id_product_catalog = product_catalog.id_product_catalog
AND product_catalog.id_product = products.id_produto
GROUP BY (products.name);
```

I tried this (returns error):

```
Transaction::join('product_stock', 'transactions.id_product_stock', '=', 'product.stock.id_product_stock')
    ->join('product_catalog', 'product_stock.id_product_catalog', '=', 'product_catalog.id_product_catalog')
    ->join('products', 'product_catalog.id_product', '=', 'products.id_product')
    ->groupBy('products.name')
    ->get([ DB::raw('SUM(transactions.amount) AS total'), DB::raw('products.name as name')]);
```

And this (returns empty):

```
DB::raw('select SUM(transactions.amount) AS total, products.name 
from transactions, product_stock, product_catalog, products
where transactions.id_product_stock = product_stock.id_prodct_stock
and product_stock.id_product_catalog = product_catalog.id_product_catalog
and product_catalog.id_product = products.id_produto
group by (products.name)');
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run the raw query (and for a complex query like this, I would stick with the raw SQL because I'm more comfortable with that), what you need to do is this:

```
$value = DB::select('select SUM(transactions.amount) AS total, products.name
    from transactions, product_stock, product_catalog, products
    where transactions.id_product_stock = product_stock.id_prodct_stock
    and product_stock.id_product_catalog = product_catalog.id_product_catalog
    and product_catalog.id_product = products.id_produto
    group by (products.name)'
);
```

[Here's the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/database#running-queries) for use of the `DB::select()` method.

`DB::raw()` is used to mark **part** of a larger query expression as raw SQL. See http://laravel.com/docs/queries#raw-expressions for details & examples.

Comment: It's no problem to cast it as an integer: `$integerValue = (int)$value`. Or just use it as-is - PHP will (in most circumstances) treat "101" (string) and 101 (integer) the same.

Answer (score 0):

quick checking their documentation it looks like you want to run your entire query as a raw expression.

http://laravel.com/docs/queries#raw-expressions

hth